# How to fill the text with white in D3

Tags: text, d3.js, colors

Below is the code to draw the text inside the circle and I want this text filled with white instead of black but it was black color instead of white. Any idea what was wrong with these code. Why the text is black instead of white

```
    d3text.text(value); // value is dynamically generated text  
    d3text.style('font-size', function() {  
    myFontSize = Math.min(2 * (radiusSize - 16), (2 * radiusSize - 16) / 
((this.getComputedTextLength() + 16) * 2) * 24);  
    myFontSize = Math.round((myFontSize < 12) ? MINFONTSIZE : myFontSize);
    return (myFontSize + 'px');  
    });  
    d3text.style('fill', 'while');  
    d3text.textAnchor = 'middle';
```

Comment: could you please put this in a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Change `d3text.style('fill', 'while');`  into `d3text.style('fill', 'white');`

Comment: What do you mean by : Change d3text.style('fill', 'while'); into d3text.style('fill', 'white');

Comment: Have a close look at the letters of *while*. =)

Comment: Maybe get an environment like Webstorm. Do you use a simple Texteditor like Notepad++?